# How to manipulate absolute values when shifting parts in an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I have the following inequality... $|4x - 2| \le 0.5$

I want to manipulate this so it is just $|x|$ on one side, and everything else on the other, but I'm not sure how the absolute value complicates things.  How would I go about this?

Comment: Can we agree that, from the definition of absolute values, $|4x - 2| \le 0.5 \implies -0.5 \leq 4x-2 \leq 0.5$ ?

Comment: You cannot get $|x|$ on one side and numbers on the other. The nearest you can get is $|x-0.5|\le 0.125$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|4x-2| \leq 0.5 \Leftrightarrow -0.5 \leq 4x-2 \leq 0.5 \Leftrightarrow 1.5 \leq 4x \leq 2.5 \Leftrightarrow \frac{3}{8} \leq x \leq \frac{5}{8}$$